# Is there a a clean way to avoid a double query when testing for an empty ActiveRecord result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In  an .html.erb file, it is quite natural to write something like this:

```
<% unless @results.empty? %>
  <ul>
    <% @results.each do |result| %>
      <li>
        <%= link_to result.name, '#' %> 
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Where @results is the result of an ActiveRecord .all query. Unfortunately this generates two queries to the database: the first looking for a count of the results (the unless condition), the second to retrieve actual results. In this case the query is particularly expensive.

I could simply convert results to an array (which would buffer the entire result set), or put complex logic in the .erb

Neither solution seems to fit the Rails/ActiveRecord design philosophy.

Is there a better way to eliminate the duplicate query?

Comment: how to concluded that its making queries twice? can you show logs?

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I've never seen Rails generate multiple queries under this circumstance.  Maybe you're seeing a validator run and think it's the `unless`?

Comment: I'm looking at the trace for this from rails server in the development environment against a postgres database. There's a query for the count, followed by a query for the actual records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails tries to be smart and not load a whole association/relation when it doesn't need it. As a result some methods on relations or associations look like their counterpart from `Enumerable` but will instead run some sql if the association is not loaded. `first`, `any?`, `include?` are examples of this.

The easiest way, when you know that this is a case when this optimisation is not paying off is to force the relation to be loaded. You could do this by converting to an array `to_a` but you might as well be more direct.

```
@results = Foo.where(...).load
```

This is also keeps @results as a relation rather than converting to an array.

Comment: This does seem to be what is happening. The "optimization" causes two queries - one with all the fields stripped out - rather than one. Rather surprised that this doesn't catch out more people. The solution works. Thanks.